# Complex Number (Locus)

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

The question is

*A complex number $z$ satisfies*

$$ | z - 2 + i | = 3 $$

(i) *Sketch the locus of points that represent $z$ on the Argand diagram.*

For this part I drew a circle with the equation

$$ (x-2)^2 + (y+1)^2 = 9 $$

Therefore a circle with radius $3$ and centre $ ( 2 , -1 ) $.

This is the part I'm stuck on

(ii) *What is the maximum value of $\operatorname{Re}(z)$?*

The answer states the maximum value is $2$

However when looking at desmos it states the maximum value is $4.828$?

[image]

Comment: The maximum value of $\text{Re}(z)$ is definitely $5$. Consider $z = 5-i$. Perhaps the problem meant to ask for the maximum value of $\text{Im}(z)$, which is $2$.

Comment: The maximum of $\Re(z)$ is $5$. The point $(5,-1)$ is on the circle. $2$ is the maximum of $\Im (z)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your second problem:

$$|z-2+i|=3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z-2+i=\pm3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\pm3+2-i\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\begin{cases}3+2-i\\
-3+2-i\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=\begin{cases}5-i\\
-1-i\end{cases}$$

---

In general:

$$|z-2+i|=3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z=(2-i)+3e^{ni}\space\space\space\space\text{with}\space n\in\mathbb{R}$$

Because, if $n\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$|((2-i)+3e^{ni})-2+i|=|3e^{ni}|=3$$

Comment: What do the arrows represent? (⟺)

Comment: @dydxx Solving an equation in steps.

Comment: Ah okay , sorry if this a stupid question but I don't really understand what z = 5-i , z = -1 - i represent? @JanEerland

Comment: @dydxx You're totally welcome!